# What scale are Maxwell's Equations valid?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, approximations

Both Maxwell's equations and quantum mechanics are used to describe the behavior of electrons in circuits.

I am confused on the interlinking between the two and the dividing line between when you use one vs the other. When must you abandon Maxwell's equations and move to quantum mechanical model when analyzing electron behavior in homogeneous media? At what scale do Maxwell's equations "fail"?

Comment: There is just no rule of thumb to say when you can use quantum mechanics or macroscopic equations just in terms of size. It depends on the problem.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "Maxwell's equations". Formally they are also valid in quantum theory, but the mathematical meaning of their symbols is different: they become "operators". This change allows us to deal with the statistical fluctuations typical of quantum theory.

Answer (score 12):

Quick clarification, based on some of the comments. This answer focuses on where Maxwell's equations are *invalid* (the title asks when Maxwell's equations are valid, but the end of the post asks when Maxwell's equations are invalid). Second, I usually consider Maxwell's equations to tell us about electromagnetic interactions, and so quantizing Maxwell's equations involves situations where *photons* are important. There are many situations where quantum mechanics is important in describing the motion of charged matter like electrons and ions, but where the electromagnetic field itself can be considered a classical field. For example, when describing conductivity in various kinds of materials, which is a major topic in condensed matter physics, the applied field generating a current can usually be considered a classical field, but quantum properties of electrons in a periodic potential are very important in determining the band structure, and therefore whether a material conducts or not.

Anyway, two important examples where Maxwell's equations are invalid would be:

(a) When the number of photons is *small* (for example, you can't use Maxwell's equations to explain the [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) for low intensities / small numbers of photons).

(b) When describing the interactions of a charged particle whose *Compton wavelength* is comparable to or larger than the distance scale (or, equivalently, energy scale) of the process you are considering. For example, you don't need QED to describe the interactions of a piece of wool with static charge (the wool has a lot of mass and a tiny Compton wavelength). You don't need QED to describe the repulsion of two electrons that are far apart from each other, compared to the localization of their wavefunction. You do need QED to describe high-energy scattering of electrons where the electrons have enough energy that their wavefunctions overlap, such as in Compton scattering.

Comment: Let me give a concrete example, consider the concept of current flow and ohm's law. How small of a section can a material get while having it still hold?

Comment: The example you gave can quickly become very complicated depending on the details of what kind of material (conductor, semiconductor, ...) and the properties of the material. To zeroth order, if you are interested in bulk properties of many electrons, you can probably use classical mechanics. If you need to know how an individual electron is interacting with nuclei and other electrons, you probably need quantum mechanics. You are very unlikely to need to quantize the electromagnetic field itself, though, unless you want interactions with individual photons like in the photoelectric effect.

Comment: But it's also not an exaggeration to say that properties of electron transport in materials is a huge part of the field of [condensed matter physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensed_matter_physics).

Comment: @FourierFlux In other words, there's not a simple formula that tells you whether or not to use classical or quantum mechanics. You have to consider each problem in a case by case basis. Material properties are particularly difficult in this regard because of *collective phenomena* like band structures, where quantum mechanics can have an important effect in explaining macroscopic properties like conductivity. The behavior of semiconductors, for example, crucially depends on quantum mechanics.

Comment: But if the material is homogenous does that simplify it? There must be some rule of thumb in regards to size. Ex a wire of certain diameter?

Comment: @FourierFlux No, the structure of the material matters a lot more than the size. Anyway a good rule of thumb is that you need quantum mechanics when you are thinking about a interactions between few particles (eg a few electrons interacting with a few lattice sites, or a few photons). Materials can actually cause more complication that break this rule of thumb, but a lot of times you can wrap up the quantum mechanical parts into some parameters and treat the material classically using those parameters.

Comment: Hmm, for example traces in ICs are still described classically but they are very small. When would you no longer be able to treat them as an microwave circuits?

Comment: @FourierFlux I suppose IC here means integrated circuit? I'm not an expert on ICs specifically. But I know there are transistors that are small enough to only contain a few tens of atoms, and then you need to treat the transistors quantum mechanically. Eg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QFET

Comment: That fits with the idea I mentioned that quantum mechanics is important when you have only a few particles, like electrons or atoms.

Comment: Andrew's answer above is a good answer to the questions "when do I need the quantized elmag field instead of Maxwell". The question "when do I need quantum physics to describe my particles" is a different and much more complicated one. In general, when the particles are close (closer than the deBroglie wavelength).

Comment: @FourierFlux As an IC designer, the best I can say is "it depends." I work on TSMC's 65nm mixed-signal node and (like all semiconductors) it takes some QM and condensed matter physics to derive the behaviors of semiconductors and transistors. The fab neatly packages that up into a model such as [BSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSIM). From there, I don't even need maxwell's emag; lumped analysis and KCL/KVL are enough at the 2.4 GHz frequency I work with, simply because my chip is tiny. Sometimes my mmwave colleagues will apply Maxwell/emag on-device, but not really quantum....

Comment: ... work at the bleeding edge nodes that actually become small enough for quantum effects may be different. I am not by any means an expert on QM, but I would still suspect that the quantum phenomena are confined to the transistor and its model, and you don't need to treat the entire circuit as a quantum system unless you've been carefully maintaining coherency in an attempt to specifically build a quantum computer. (this is mostly an informed guess, nobody in my lab/department works at that scale at the moment)

Comment: I'd suggest mentioning at the start those cases are ones where Maxwell's equations are invalid, since the OP question title asks when they're valid but the close of the question text asks when they're invalid.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions and clarifications. I added a disclaimer to the top of my answer to explain the perspective it is coming from.

Answer (score 5):

Two of Maxwell's equations assume a "continuity" in electricity where there is in fact "quantization".

Gauss's Law

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$$

and Ampere's Circuital Law with Maxwell's correction

$$\nabla \times \vec{B} = \mu_0 \left(\vec{J} + \varepsilon_0\frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial t}\right)$$

refer to $\rho$ (charge density) and $\vec{J}$ current density.

On a atomic/microscopic scale, however, these terms are problematic, as electric charge and electric current are *quantized*. Therefore, on a microscopic level, quantum electro-dynamics must be used.

Comment: Not really. In their integral form, the equations are valid for continuous, discrete, and mixed distributions of charge and fields. This is also true in their differential form, keeping in mind that the various fields are then generalized functions (with Dirac deltas etc).